# Cannot connect to Oracle using SID

Tags: java, oracle, spring, database-connection

I m having web application where i connect with oracle with spring
my application is not working if i give SID in xml file

xml file entry is

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"><value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:XXX</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>xx</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>xx</value>
    </property></bean>
```

Even i am unable to connect using Oracle SQL Developer with SID. but if i give service name it is working properly.

Can you plz help me out.